# Launch xApi (TinCan) package at LMS with oAuth on LRS

Tags: tin-can-api, lrs, xapi

What url parameters needs to launch **xApi (TinCan api)** package with **oAuth** authorization on LRS?

I found only examples with basic auth:

```
?endpoint=https://lrs.example.com/xAPI/
&auth=Basic%20efnkn4kn3jk3nfkwefoew
&actor={"name": "username", "mbox": "mailto:email@example.com", "objectType": "Agent"}
&registration=ffbe80cc-1732-11ea-8d71-362b9e155666
&activity_id=http://www.example.com/LA1/001/intro
```

And params with oAuth authorization, but for CMI5:

```
?endpoint=https://lrs.example.gov/xAPI/
&fetch=http://test/token&actor={"objectType": "Agent","account": 
{"homePage": "http://www.example.com","name": "1625378"}
&registration=760e3480-ba55-4991-94b0-01820dbd23a4
&activityId=http://www.example.com/LA1/001/intro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no additional URL parameters when doing OAuth launch based on the Tin Can launch guidelines. The LRS endpoint should be all that is needed, the rest of the authentication process uses resources provided by the LRS. See the various OAuth workflows in the xAPI specification itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212579/1464957 for more.